# dajaxice error 'str' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Tags: python, django, dajaxice

I tried to use dajaxice for refreshing my table but I see an error.

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/bank/index1/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'meli',
 'django_tables2',
 'dajaxice',
 'django_jalali')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  187.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  26.                 patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py" in patch_vary_headers
  142.     if response.has_header('Vary'):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /bank/index1/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

This is my view:

```
def index1(request):

    data = MelliTable(ModelMelli.objects.filter(check=False))
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 20}).configure(table)
    table = render_to_string('meli/index.html', {'data': data })
    return simplejson.dumps({'table':table})
dajaxice_functions.register(index1)
```

And my js is :

```
<script>
function my_callback(data){
    if(data!=Dajaxice.EXCEPTION){
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data.table;
    }
    else{
        alert('Error');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: traceback: http://dpaste.com/1270328/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-dajaxice` works by wrapping view functions, here `index1` in your code, with special handler; and serving them through dynamically matched urls instead of `/bank/index1/`.
Thus you don't have to define urlpattern `/bank/index1/` for the `index1`, just access it through [Dajaxice interface](http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html), perhaps `Dajaxice.bank.index1(my_callback)` here.

The error was caused by the reason that a normal Django view is expected to return an `HttpResponse()` instance, whilst `index1` returns a string here (When you call through dajaxice interface, the special handler mentioned above would put the string to an `HttpResponse` w/o problem)

Comment: tnx for your answer. can you help me to findout a way to update my table in view? I have no idea about how to do it

Comment: @nim4n Please post your js code that triggers the ajax operations.

Answer (score 0):

I modify my view and put the dajaxice function to ajax.py and this is my js for calling it:

```
<script>
function setupRefresh() {
    setTimeout("Dajaxice.meli.refresh(my_callback)", 5000); // milliseconds
}
</script>
```

I can see the script call my djaxice in console but I don't know what should i write in my_callback js function to change the table!

```
5/Jun/2013 23:25:43] "POST /dajaxice/meli.refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580
[25/Jun/2013 23:25:48] "POST /dajaxice/meli.refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580
[25/Jun/2013 23:25:53] "POST /dajaxice/meli.refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580
[25/Jun/2013 23:25:58] "POST /dajaxice/meli.refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580
[25/Jun/2013 23:26:03] "POST /dajaxice/meli.refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580
```

view:

```
def index2(request):

    table = MelliTable(ModelMelli.objects.filter(check=True))

    #table.paginate(page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=4)
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 20}).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'meli/index1.html', {'table': table })
```

ajax:

```
def refresh(request):
    message = ""
    table = MelliTable(ModelMelli.objects.filter(check=True))
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 20}).configure(table)
    table1 = render_to_string('meli/index.html', {'table': table, 'message': message })
    return simplejson.dumps({'table1':table1})

dajaxice_functions.register(refresh)
```

and my template is:

```
{% extends "meli/base.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block content %}
<script>
function setupRefresh() {
    setTimeout("Dajaxice.meli.refresh(my_callback)", 5000); // milliseconds
}
</script>

            {% render_table table %}            
{% endblock %}
```